# what does it mean "stores scoped to user"

Tags: jenkins

I'm very new to jenkins and Im playing around manage credentials screen. Would like to understand

1. what does it mean "stores scoped to user:john"(I logged into jenkins account as user John)
2. And why under store only john user is shown? And in what use case multiple stores will be shown?

[image]